# Firestore orderBy Timestamp object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to order a query by timestamp.

In my document I have a field called "date" which has this form:

```
date = {
   nanoseconds: 963000000,
   seconds: 1594917688
}
```

In my code I have this:

```
let photosArray = [];

firebase
  .getDatabase()
  .collection("photos")
  .doc(firebase.getCurrentUser().uid)
  .collection("userPhotos")
  .orderBy("date", "asc") // Sorted by date in ascending direction
  .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      let changes = snapshot.docChanges();
      changes.forEach((change) => {
         if (change.type === "added") {
            // Get the new photo
            const photo = change.doc.data();

            // Add the photo to the photos list
            photosArray.push(photo);
          }
       });

       // The last photo is at the top of the list
       setPhotos(photosArray);
```

But when I render the list of photos, they are unsorted... For example: the first one taken 2 hours ago, the second one taken 1 minute ago, and the last one taken 2 years ago.

### UPDATE

This is how I store the date in firestore

Firebase.js:

```
getTimestamp = () => firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
```

PhotoUploader.js

```
 await firestore
    .collection("photos")
    .doc(userId)
    .collection("userPhotos")
    .add({
        id,
        date: firebase.getTimestamp(),
     });
```

Comment: Does your "date" field use the firebase timestamp type? E.g., if you login to the firebase console, is date currently being stored as a timestamp (as opposed to a number or string).

Comment: Yeah, I am using firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your date field shows a map with two nested fields, that is not really a timestamp, and it won't sort the way you expect.  You should take a look at the code that adds the date field to the document, and make sure it uses a timestamp correctly.  Either that, or use a single timestamp numeric value that will sort the way you expect.

Comment: I am using firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()) to store the date

Comment: As in firestore there is no Date type, and firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()) returns a map... shloud I use a string to store the date? Also I have thought to store only the seconds and ignore the nanoseconds but it will maybe work incorrectly.

Comment: You can just write a Date object.  It will be converted to a Firestore Timestamp by the Firestore SDK.  Without seeing all of the relevant code, it's not possible to see what you might be doing wrong.  But if you see two fields split out like that, you are definitely doing something wrong.

Comment: I have updated the question. Now you can see how I store the date. The thing is that in this documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp the timestamp have those two properties I said (seconds + nanoseconds) but I suppose that if I do orderBy("date") as I did, it will sort by some of the properties of the map instance itself

Comment: Just use `new Date()` to set the date field, or `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` to use the server's time.

Comment: I have done this and having the same trouble :C  I suppose the error is in my code. Anyways, thank you!

Comment: The seconds/nanoseconds map is fine, as that's just how the raw timestamp is displayed with [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp). Did you try `new Date()` like Doug mentioned? Are your dates stored correctly when you go to the console? Maybe you could post screenshot?